# Mac Flash CS4 font not showing up

Tags: flash, fonts

I just installed a couple of fonts on my Mac.
The font shows up in my Photoshop, but not in the Flash font list.

I already clear the font cache, reboot, put fonts in all folders (/Library/..., /Users/... etc)

What could be causing it?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply.
Font is still broken but I found a workaround that I'm fine with.

So if you change the font through the top nav, instead of the regular text widget, it works.

Tee

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if ya'll are still looking for a solution, but I was having the same problem with one of my fonts. Switching the text field from TLF text to Classic text in the properties pane worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link for the MAC OS. If it works anything like windows there are font folders in different locations but if you want to share them between applications you will have to put them into a system folder. Macs have 5 different locations where fonts can be placed. I found this link which explains it for you.

[Apple Font Installation](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2435)

Answer (score 0):

I know exactly what you mean, the fonts are installed in ALL the right places, they show up in Dreamweaver, Photoshop, etc. except Flash.

I have tried everything, nothing seems to correct this inherent Flash problem. No matter what Font List or Pref file you delete.

Anyone else have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

(Font not showing up in Flash)

Solution for me: 2 steps

1. Reinstalled Helvetica Neue LT Std font into System>Library>Fonts (if you have the original font... if not just try step 2.)
2. Moved all fonts from MacHD>Library>Fonts TO System>Library>Fonts (so no fonts are in the MacHD>Library>Fonts location) I also moved all fonts from the User>Library>Fonts to the System>Library>Fonts location.

   - [co-worker found that works for all of his fonts except one, so he put that one font in the User>Library>fonts folder and it works.]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem also. My problem was solved by installing the font in the system's font folder.

Also, if you are using apple's default font app "Font Book", you may need to go to preferences and change the "default install location". If you are adding the font through Font Book, it may be installing the font to the "User's" font folder, which might be causing the font to not show up.

Answer (score 0):

I dragged some new Helveticas directly into Font Book's HD fonts, it didn't work... Then I moved them into Font Book's user fonts, and, even with conflicts, it started working.  Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me everytime I have this issue.

Move ALL the fonts out of both user and computer library font folders...into a temporary folder. This essentially uninstalls them. Then move the misbehaving fonts back into the computer font folder (home/library/fonts). Then add the other fonts t back into the folder as well, with no issues.